# Switching views in ViewFlipper

Tags: android

Is there a way to switch views in a ViewFlipper just like on Home screen, where we have small dots at the bottom of the screen and on clicking on them we can switch views.

Thanks,
Farha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Step #1: Create a graphic with a dot

Step #2: Put copies of that graphic in the Views of your `ViewFlipper` via `ImageView` widgets, for however many dots you want

Step #3: Add an `OnClickListener` to each `ImageView` widget

Step #4: In `onClick()`, switch the `ViewFlipper` as desired

Comment: Works and it is fast solution.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is a better thing these days =) flowview by Patrik Åkerfeldt. See here:

https://github.com/pakerfeldt/android-viewflow