# Android 3 to 4 dots on top of screen indicating current view sample code

Tags: android, android-layout, viewflipper

I Have created an android app, which has view flipper and it has 4 child views

When I swipe from right to left it changes and moves on to next screen 
, but I want something that indicates the current view like there are 3 to 4 dots in android homescreen, which represents the current view. Something similar or if there is any different way to show it would be helpful. Please help. Please let me know the code.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is the [ViewPagerIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator) created by Jake Wharton. It was built for a ViewPager (obviously), but you can use parts of it and adjust it to your view flipper.

Answer (score 2):

you have to create a graphic first and than put that graphic to ur views through imageview.....go through the below link you'll get ur exact answer.......

[Switching views in ViewFlipper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406628/switching-views-in-viewflipper)